# Microsoft PEX with NUnit

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, pex

I am thinking of using Microsoft PEX tools for my project, but I would much rather use NUnit instead of MSUnit. Apparently, [PEX Extensions project](http://pex.codeplex.com) was specifically created for that, but it has no releases now, and appears to be dead. Has anyone been able to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [this Post](http://pex.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=4278), NUnit test generation is now part of Pex.

[Here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/releasenotes.aspx#0_10_40408_0) is more information on the subject.